# Undefined property in an "hasOne" relation

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, one-to-one

I tried a lot of possibilities and I have all the time the same error.

Maybe you should help me... Hope so! I am working on Laravel 4.2

I have two tables :

users :

$table->increments('id');
 $table->string('email', 50);
...

account :

$table->increments('id');
 $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

I have 2 models :

User :

```
public function account()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Account', 'id','user_id');
    }
```

Account :

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'id');
    }
```

Now I would like to get the user_id in the account table by the relationship :

```
$userId = Auth::id();
$account = User::find($userId)->Account()->user_id;
```

I get this error : ErrorException
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$user_id

Could you help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User::find($userId)->Account()` actually return an object of type `HasOne`, you need to use `User::find($userId)->Account()->get()` to get an array containing actual Account object so `User::find($userId)->Account()->get()[0]` actually get you the Account object. and `User::find($userId)->Account->user_id` is an laravel build-in feature that automatically map the Account object, so you get the Account object directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$account = User::find($userId)->Account->user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case `User::find($userId)->account` doesn't work, check if `getAccountAttribute()`  doesn't exist.